# MVC View and JavaScript file

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view

When inside a View, within MVC, and you have your JavaScript, I tried to move it to a JavaScript file in the same directory, and it reports it can not file the javascript file

As an example I user NerdDinner and the DinnerForm.aspx, created a JavaScript file in the same directory as the DinnerForm.aspx called DinnerForm.js and referenced it in the aspx file, as below:

Here is the issue, I need to keep my JavaScript file near if not in the same directory in the project as DinnerForm.aspx, how do I go about doing this?

I don't want to place the full path, eg:  "~\views\dinners\dinnerform.js"   as this is just a work around, and will cause issues later

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript files by convention should be placed in project's *Scripts* folder and could be linked as

```
<script src="<%= Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.3.2.js") %>"
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't have the JavaScript files in the Views folder as it does not actually exist to the browser. If you have a look at the Web.config file in the Views folder, you'll see that it is set to the `HttpNotFoundHandler` handler. That means it returns 404 for all requests to its folder.

Why not put them in the Scripts folder? You could always have sub folder under it.

E.g. `/Scripts/Dinner/dinnerform.js`

Comment: Interesting info about HttpNotFoundHandler. Thanks!

Comment: Yes I understand that you can do this, however it detaches the html from the JavaScript, make it hard to maintain at a later stage hence the reason for not doing this.

At present the JavaScript is inside the html view, so moving it to yet another directory just adds to the complexity.